# How to get data from other activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities such as `Activity` A and B and I'm trying to pass two different strings from A to B using `Bundle` and `startActivity(intent)`.

Like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("vidoedetails", filedetails);
//bundle.putString("videoname", filename);


intent.putExtras(bundle);
//intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
//intent.putExtra("vidoefiledetails", filedetails);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in class B I'm using two `TextView`s to display the strings from class A seperately.

Like that:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

filedetails = extras.getString("videodetails");
filename = extras.getString("videoname");
```

The problem is `filedetils` get printed in class B but not the file name.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have a typo:

```
bundle.putString("vidoedetails", filedetails);
```

should be

```
bundle.putString("videodetails", filedetails);
```

Comment: It took me like 40 seconds to spot the difference :S

Answer (score 9):

I know I am 9 days late on this answer, but this is a good example of why I create a constants class.  With a constants class, it doesnt matter if it is misspelled ("video" -> "vidoe") because it will be 'misspelled' in both places as you are referencing it through a well known location.

Constants.java

```
public static String WELL_KNOWN_STRING "org.example.stackoverflow.4792829";
```

Activity1.java

```
bundle.putString(Constants.WELL_KNOWN_STRING, filedetails);
```

Activity2.java

```
filedetails = extras.getString(Constants.WELL_KNOWN_STRING);
```

Comment: Always do this. If you don't, you're going to waste a ton of time with string mismatch bugs. When you waste time with string mismatch bugs, the sun will go down and it will get dark without you noticing. When it gets dark without you noticing, you will get eaten by a grue. Don't get eaten by a grue. Define your key strings as constants.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you spelled wrongly videodetails:
Yours: vid**OE**details 
Correct: vid**EO**details

Answer (score 0):

```
// First activity
actvty_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),SECONDACTIVITY.class);    
        startActivityForResult(i, STATIC_INTEGER_VALUE);
    }
});

/* This function gets the value from the other activity where we have passed a value on calling this activity */ 
public void activity_value() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras=i.getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        // This is necessary for the retrv_value
        rtrv_value = extras.getString("key");

        if(!(rtrv_value.isEmpty())) {
            // It displays if the retrieved value is not equal to zero
            myselection.setText("Your partner says = " + rtrv_value);
        }
    }
}


// Second activity
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FIRSTACTIVITY.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", txt1.getText().toString());
        // Here key is just the "Reference Name" and txt1 is the EditText value
        intent.putExtras(bundle);               
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to pass data between Activities. This is just an example from a tutorial I was following. I have a splash screen that runs for 5 seconds and then it would kill the sound clip from:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
}
```

I decided I wanted the sound clip to continue playing into the next activity while still being able to kill/release it from there, so I made the sound clip, MediaPlayer object, public and static, similar to how out in System.out is a public static object. Being new to Android dev but not new to Java dev, I did it this way.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    public static MediaPlayer ourSong; // <----- Created the object to be shared
                                        // this way

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.dubstep);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "expectusafterlun.ch.androidtutorial.MENU");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Then from the next activity, or any other activity, I could access that MediaPlayer object.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String activities[] = { "Count", "TextPlay", "Email", "Camera", "example4",
            "example5", "example6" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, activities));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Splash.ourSong.release(); // <----- Accessing data from another Activity
                                    // here
    }

}
```