# Sending data from one activity to the other

Tags: android, android-intent

What are the diffrent kinds of data that can be passed from an activity to another?

Comment: This kind of question was answered several times in the last days. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792829/how-to-get-data-from-other-activity-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758383/reterive-value-from-one-activity-to-another-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any primitive data types and also ArrayLists.
Please use the eclipse and see the references which will list down all available methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one activity to another using extras. (putExtra() & getExtra())

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it through an sqlite database.